# How extract @attributes from stdClass Object?

Tags: php, stdclass

How i can extract the attributes from a stdClass Object? I have the variable `$data`. Doing a `print_r` to it i get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => cover
            [title] => Cover
        )

    [text] => text
)
```

No problem when i try to read `text`. But when i try to read `id` and `title` with `$data["id"]` and `$data["title"]` get error:

*Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...*

How i can solve it? The unique chance is convert in array using `json_encode`/`json_decode`? Not there is a solution more object oriented?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Searching for that error would have revealed that you're not dealing with an array. How to get an array instead of an object is explained in the link above.

Comment: Are you reading XML?  If so, then look into SimpleXML to help.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you've converted XML to a SimpleXML object, then converted it to JSON, and converted it back to a much less useful object. If so, don't. Read [the usage examples for SimpleXML in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php)  instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you'd just use the name of the attribute like this:

```
$data->foo
```

However, since your attribute name `@attributes` contains a special character, you have to use this extended syntax:

```
$data->{'@attributes'}
```

Then, you can further reference its subkeys:

```
$id = $data->{'@attributes'}->id;
```

Alternatively, you could pass a truthy value as the second argument of json_decode() and then you'll get an array instead of an object:

```
$data = json_decode($raw, true);
$id = $data['@attributes']['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know about this sintax.